# Change shortcut for cursor jump to space

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to change the shortcut "left/right arrow - option(alt)" to jump lines with "left/right arrow - cmd" ?
Currently the arrow/cmd shortcut takes me to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's currently possible. You can rebind the modifier keys under System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard > Modifier Keys..., although that's probably not what you're looking for.